# Passing a counter through an intent to a new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, counter

i am developing a kids learning development application and i want to have a score on the top of the screen to show them how many questions they got correct so far. I have an if statement that states if they spell the answer with the correct letter then they are moved onto the next activity but as they move i want their score to update. Looking to pass the counter through the intent to the second activity but when i click the submit button the app crashes. 
here is the first class

```
package com.helloworld.erica.alphaanimals;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.helloworld.erica.alphaanimals.R.id.imageView;
public class button_a extends Activity {

private Button button_b;
TextView scoreText;
int counter = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.button_a);

    //final TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);

    final ImageView ImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(imageView);
    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText answerA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answerA);
            String toCompare = answerA.getText().toString();
            TextView score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);


            if(toCompare.startsWith("A")) {
                Intent intent_b = new Intent(button_a.this, button_b.class);
                intent_b.putExtra("username", score.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent_b);
                counter++;
                scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(counter));

                Toast.makeText(button_a.this, "Well Done, correct answer!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(button_a.this, "Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });

}
```

}
 here is the second

```
package com.helloworld.erica.alphaanimals;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText; 
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class button_b extends Activity {
private Button button_c;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.button_b);
    final ImageView ImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(imageView);
    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    TextView scoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreText);
    scoreText.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("username"));

    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText answerB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answerB);
            String toCompare = answerB.getText().toString();

            if(toCompare.startsWith("B")) {
                Intent intent_c = new Intent(button_b.this, button_c.class);
                startActivity(intent_c);
                //ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bear);
                Toast.makeText(button_b.this, "Well Done, correct answer!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(button_b.this, "Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of crash.

Comment: set scoretext "counter++;
                scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(counter));" before intent

Comment: Your `scoreText` is `null` in your `button_a`activity. Also call this   `counter++;
                scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(counter));` before you start new activity.

Comment: Got it to stop crashing, had to change               scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(counter)); to                 score.setText(Integer.toString(counter));

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: Got it working, Thank you!!

Comment: Please mark any one answer as correct answer so others getting help from this. Happy to help you bro @eee :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Your getting Text before setting up so made below changes:

```
            counter++;
            scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
intent_b.putExtra("username", score.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent_b);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check the error on Android Monitor in Android Studio, will be shown what the error and you can paste it here. it will be helpful to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(toCompare.startsWith("A")) {

                    counter++;
                    score.setText(Integer.toString(counter));

                    Toast.makeText(button_a.this, "Well Done, correct answer!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent intent_b = new Intent(button_a.this, button_b.class);
                    intent_b.putExtra("username", score.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent_b);

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(button_a.this, "Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

There is no scoreText in first activity. Your TextView name is score, so change it and also the order of statements is not correct. Intent should be after counter++ and setting text in TextView.